# Microsoft ADF - Operationalizing subqueries

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Updating my request with more details:

[screenshot of query 1 and 2 in pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNOwT.png)

**SQl for query 1:**

```
SELECT
        vf.EncounterKey
    FROM
        VisitFact vf
    INNER JOIN
        DepartmentDim dd
    ON vf.[DepartmentKey] = dd.DepartmentKey
    INNER JOIN EncounterFact ef
    ON ef.EncounterKey = vf.EncounterKey
    INNER JOIN DateDim AppointmentDate
    ON AppointmentDate.DateKey = vf.AppointmentDateKey

    WHERE
        vf.[Count] = 1
        AND dd.DepartmentEpicId IN (@{pipeline().parameters.DepartmentEpicIDs})
        AND
        (
        --AppointmentDate.DateValue BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day,21,GETDATE())  --Appointment up to 21 days in the future
        --OR
        ef.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() --Encounter/visit 3 up to 3 days ago
        )
```

**SQl for query 2:**

--Procedure Orders

```
SELECT 
pof.ProcedureOrderKey, pof.PatientDurableKey, pof.EncounterKey, pof.ProcedureDurableKey, pof.OrderedDateKey, pof.OrderedTimeOfDayKey,
pof.ProcedureOrderEpicId, pof.[Type], pof.Mode, pof.[Status], pof.StandingStatus, pof._CreationInstant, pof._LastUpdatedInstant,
pd.[Name],
pof.OrderedByProviderDurableKey,
pof.AuthorizedByProviderDurableKey,
pd.[Code],
pd.ProcedureEpicId
FROM /*[Kit].*/[ProcedureOrderFact] pof
INNER JOIN /*kit.*/ProcedureDim pd
ON pd.DurableKey = pof.ProcedureDurableKey
AND pd.IsCurrent = 1
WHERE [EncounterKey] 
IN  concat(variables('WoundEncQ2'))
```

Is it possible to use a set variable or other activity to 'hold' the query for Q1 so that can be referenced directly within the SQL of Q2 and other queries, thus only requiring an update in 1 place if Q1 needs to be modified?

Comment: I have done something similar by having the query sql stored in a global variable and then referencing the global variable where you need it.  I was doing a POC where the sql was stored in a separate file and put into the global variable at deployment time.  I was using a Script activity but it should work in a Copy activity too.

Comment: you could also store the sql for the query elsewhere and retrieve it with a Lookup activity.

Comment: Hi @ScottMildenberger, thank you for the quick reply. In terms of the lookup activity, would you be able to reference that in the actual sql of another query in the pipeline though? For my example, query1 is grabbing a subset of medical patients based on clinical data and query 2 is grabbing a specific set of medical appointments and references query 1 in the WHERE clause to ensure the visit are only for patients from query 1. Would query 2 be able to reference a lookup activity that includes query 1?

Comment: it could if the query 1 is the sql top be inserted.  the sql ran in query 2 would be built by concatenating strings and the value from query1.  Hard to get more specific without a specific example.  The next comment is what I have in a Script activity, it is a bit messy to get setup but now I have a pipeline driven by a json control file to handle a bunch of tables.  <atsign> was used to indicate an @ was present, SO thought I was mentioning users.....

Comment: <atsign>replace(concat('declare <atsign>inputParm as [dbo].[udtt_',pipeline().parameters.tableControl.sinkTableName,']; 
insert into @inputParm select ''ADF'' as [_meta.last_modified_by],null as [_meta.last_modified_by_sys],convert(datetime, null) as [_meta.last_modified],convert(bit, null) as [_meta.removed],''ADF'' as [_meta.source] ',
',', pipeline().parameters.tableControl.stagingColumns,' from', ' staging.[',pipeline().parameters.tableControl.sinkTableName,'];',
' exec ',pipeline().parameters.tableControl.storedProcedureName, ' <atsign>inputParm;'), '\n', ' ')

Comment: Hey @ScottMildenberger, does my updated description above help or change how you'd go about essentially building a given query as a building block to be used across multiple copy data activities?

Comment: What does that variable actually contain?  You probably want to concat the entire sql statement through the 'IN' with the variable value. Something like concat('your sql here IN ', variables('WoundEncQ2')) but it depends what the variable value is.  You are building your entire sql statement dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this with two tables. I took distinct ids from Table T1 using script activity and stored it in variable. Then used the same variable in Copy activity source Query for extracting the records from T2 where id is in the stored variable. Below are the steps.

- Sample tables T1 and T2 are taken as in below image.

[image]

- Script activity is taken and in that Query is written to extract the unique id values from T1
  `select distinct id from T1`

[image]

**Output of script activity 1**

[image]

- Result of Script activity 1 is stored in a variable **var1** ( **array** datatype). Varible var1 is defined using set variable activity.
  `@activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows`

[image]

**Output of Set Variable 1**

[image]

- The above array var1 should be converted to comma separated values. Thus, another variable **var2** of string datatype is created.
  `join(variables('var1'), ',')` will join every array element of array together with comma delimiter. Output will look like

```
{
    "name": "var2",
    "value": "{\"id\":101},{\"id\":102}"
}
```

To remove **id** from the data, var2 should be set as
`@replace(replace(join(variables('var1'), ','), '{"id":', ''), '}', '')`

**Output of set variable2 activity**

[image]

- Copy activity is used for extracting the records from T2 whose ids are available in T1. Query used here is
  `select * from T2 where id in (@{variables('var2')})`

[image]

**Input of Copy activity**

[image]

In this way, we can refer a query in another query.

**Other Approach:**
Like Scott has commented, we can concatenate the Query with the variable in which we stored the inner Query. Below are the steps,

- Sub Query is stored in variable **var3** (string type) using set variable activity.
  [image]
- In copy activity, Source Query is given as below for concatenating the Query with variable
  `@concat('select * from T1 where id in (',variables('var3'),')')`

[image]

**Input of copy activity while executing pipeline**

[image]

By this approach also, we can achieve the same.